# Get the latest folder in android using shell command

Tags: android, shell

i'm writing a shell script for android and i need to get the last created  directory, i would usually use
`ls -t | head -1` but `ls -t` gives me the error "ls: Unknown option '-t'"

is there another shell command that can order the files by time-stamp or another way to do that **in android**? the busy box is more limited

Comment: this post is for linux\unix, it didn't work in my android tablet

Comment: yes i tried that, it says "ls: Unknown option '-E'" , and without the -E it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`stat` is available in BusyBox](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html), which means that you could do something like this:

```
stat -c '%Y %n' */ | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

This passes the names of all directories (paths ending in a slash) to `stat`, which prints the last modification time (seconds since the UNIX epoch) and the filename. These are sorted in reverse numerical order and then the time field is stripped from each line.

This assumes that your directory names don't contain newlines, otherwise the sorting would be messed up.

Comment: it works great, just like ls -t, thanks.      

so */ is for folders and * to sort all files

Comment: Yes, `*` will expand to all paths, whereas `*/` will expand only to paths ending in `/`, so won't match any files.